# Rename "pivot" to "google-sheets-query-pivot" or at least "query-pivot"

Tags: discussion, retag-request

All questions that link to [pivot](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pivot) refer to the pivot functionality within [google-sheets-query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-query). I've submitted usage guidance to it which will hopefully get approved.

Due to (currently) having no usage guidance, it causes users to accidentally confuse it with [pivot-table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pivot-table), which is unrelated.

Even if usage guidance gets added, it will be much clearer to just call it directly what it means: [google-sheets-query-pivot](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-query-pivot) or at least [query-pivot](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-pivot).

Comment: I've tagged it as "bug" because it causes users to tag their questions wrongly or just don't tag it since they don't know they should.

Comment: [tag:bug] should be used to indicate that it was found "an erroneous or unexpected behavior in the system that needs to be fixed" not b/c a tag is being not used as expected.